# Distinguish between fancybox's for custom css

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to do some customer-mandated inconsistencies in the styling of different fancyboxes.

I can't seem to figure out a way to distinguish between which fancybox is open using a class or an ID or anything.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[Fancybox 2](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) has a `wrapCSS` option which lets you add a custom class to the lightbox for styling.

Like so:

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox();

$(".photo").fancybox({
    wrapCSS : 'photo-lightbox-class'
});

$(".video").fancybox({
    wrapCSS : 'video-lightbox-class'
});
```

Comment: Thank you and +1. Actually I've already found it in [fancybox docs](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) but only this answer helped me to realize, that it adds class to `.fancybox-wrap`, not just css styles, that follows form property's name. So maybe developer could name it `addClass` instead to make it clear

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using separate calls to fancybox() and the onX parameters. For example:

```
$('.ProductThumbImage a').fancybox({
    padding: 30,
    margin: 0,
    autoScale: true,
    onStart: function() {
        $('#fancybox-content').css('padding', '8px');
    },
    onClosed: function() {
        $('#fancybox-content').css('padding', '0');
    }
});
```

The same fancybox is used for all instances apparently, so you can simply add/remove styles or classes to it based upon which link was clicked.

Comment: You can also access element using `this.element` inside callbacks to do some customization